# Python script does not receive arguments after installing Visual Studio 2015

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-2015

I just installed Visual Studio 2015. Now my Python scripts don't receive command-line arguments anymore.

```
Desktop> python foo.py hello foo
['C:\\Users\\niklas\\Desktop\\foo.py', 'hello', 'foo']
F:\Python34\python.exe
Desktop>
Desktop> foo.py hello foo
['C:\\Users\\niklas\\Desktop\\foo.py']
F:\Python34\python.exe
```

Both end up being executed with the same Python executable. How can I fix this?

Comment: .PY files should be associated with the `Python.File` progid. You can update this for the local machine using an elevated command prompt to run `assoc .PY=Python.File`. You may also need to select this for your current user using Explorer's "Open With" dialog.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks! I ran this command as administrator and updated `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\open\command` to the value `"F:\Python34\python.exe" "%L" %*` That fixed it!